# MediaCodec and the output format

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I am trying to write a video player using the MediaDecoder class, i came across a problem that its blocking my development,

here is a code snippet

```
extractor = new MediaExtractor();
extractor.setDataSource(filename);

MediaFormat format = extractor.getTrackFormat(i);
extractor.selectTrack(0);

MediaCodec decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
decoder.configure(format, null, null, 0);

decoder.start();

ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = decoder.getInputBuffers();
ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();

Log.d(TAG, " "+decoder.getOutputFormat());
```

The problem is the output format printed changes with each device making it impossible to print it out to an Open GL texture.

Is there a way to force the decoder to output always the same format?
 If no, does anyone knows of any libraries available to make the conversion?

Thanks a lot for any insights

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The decoder's output format can't be set.  In fact, you probably shouldn't even examine it until you receive an updated `MediaFormat` from `dequeueOutputBuffer()` -- before the first chunk of data is returned, you'll get a `MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED` result.

If you want to access the decoded frame from OpenGL ES, you should create a `Surface` from a `SurfaceTexture` and pass that into the decoder `configure()` call.  It's more efficient, and doesn't require you to know anything about the data format.

For an example, see the [DecodeEditEncodeTest.java CTS test](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#DecodeEditEncodeTest), and note in particular the [OutputSurface](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/OutputSurface.java) class and how it's used in `checkVideoFile()`.